# Facebook API webhook - Get informations about shared posts

Tags: facebook, api

I'm working with Facebook API **webhook**. Currently, I can make an API call and get all the data relating to likes and comments done on a post.

For example when someone comment a post, i receive, thanks to Facebook API webhook these informations :

```
(
[entry] => Array
    (
        [0] => stdClass Object
            (
                [changes] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => stdClass Object
                            (
                                [field] => feed
                                [value] => stdClass Object
                                    (
                                        [parent_id] => ...
                                        [sender_name] => ...
                                        [comment_id] => ...
                                        [sender_id] => ..
                                        [item] => comment
                                        [verb] => add
                                        [created_time] => 1467111568
                                        [post_id] => ..
                                        [message] => comment
                                    )

                            )

                    )

                [id] => ...
                [time] => 1467111568
            )
     )
  )
```

The same thing when someone like or publish a post ! 
But when someone share a post i'm not receiving anything from FACEBOOK API webhook ! Can someone help me to receive updates when someone share a post with Facebook API webhook.

thanks